# Reading then writing with select() in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

How would I read input data from some client, then use that data to make a calculation, then write back to the client the results. What I have now will take input data, but when I write back my client program doesn't seem to get anything. Heres what I have now. Its not the whole code but any variables that aren't defined should have a clear meaning. Do I need to make a writefd and check that? I need to make sure it gets back to the correct client and don't understand how to do this?

```
 while(TRUE) 
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = master_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
    {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket[i];
        if(sd > 0)
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
        if(sd > max_sd)
            max_sd = sd;
    }
    //waiting for activity
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , &writefds, NULL , NULL);    
    if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
    {
        printf("select error");
    }

if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
    {

        recv(new_socket,buffer,1025,0);
        printf(buffer); // i recieve input data, though it isn't correct, but at least something is recieved. 
        //add new socket to array of sockets

        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            //if position is empty
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
            {
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);
                send(new_socket, "here", strlen("here"),0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "my client program doesn't seem to get anything". How are you determining that? For starters you should check the return status of all your function calls. In particular if you think the send is failing then check the return value of `send` to see if it actually succeeded or not. Also, your send is not sending the `NUL` terminator in the string so if the client is expecting that to be a valid string you will have problems. To send the NUL terminator the size needs to be `strlen("here")+1`.

Comment: *What* client program? This program sends `"here"`. NB It is never correct to call `recv()` without storing the return value in a variable, checking it for zero, checking it for -1, and otherwise using it as the count of data received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `master_socket` is marked as readable, you are calling `recv()` on `new_socket` instead.  Assuming `master_socket` is your listening server socket, you need to call `accept()` instead to receive a new client.  Do not call `recv()` unless `select()` tells you that a specific client is readable, and then read from that client.

Try something more like this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < max_clients; ++i)
    client_socket[i] = -1;

...

while (TRUE) 
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = master_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; ++i)
    {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket[i];
        if (sd > -1)
        {
            FD_SET(sd, &readfds);
            if (sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }
    }

    //waiting for activity
    activity = select(max_sd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (activity < 0)
    {
        if (errno != EINTR)
            printf("select error");
    }
    else
    {
        //check master socket to accept from
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
        {
            new_socket = accept(master_socket, NULL, NULL);
            if (new_socket < 0)
            {
                printf("accept error");
            }
            else
            {
                //add new socket to array of sockets
                for (i = 0; i < max_clients; ++i)
                {
                    //if position is empty
                    if (client_socket[i] == -1)
                    {
                        client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                        printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);
                        send(new_socket, "here", strlen("here"), 0);
                        new_socket = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // close new socket if no room for it
                if (new_socket > -1)
                    close(new_socket);
            }
        }

        //check child sockets to read from
        for (i = 0 ; i < max_clients; ++i) 
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];
            if (sd > -1)
            {
                if (FD_ISSET(sd, &readfds)) 
                {
                    len = recv(sd, buffer, 1025, 0);
                    if (len > 0)
                    {
                        // data received
                        buffer[len] = 0; // make sure it is null terminated
                        printf("data: %s", buffer);
                        // or: printf("data: %.*s", len, buffer);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (len == 0)
                            printf("disconnected");
                        else
                            printf("recv error");

                        printf("Removing from list of sockets at %d\n", i);
                        close(sd);
                        client_socket[i] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hard to believe this is the real code. He claims he received something via `new_socket`, which couldn't have happened unless he had an `accept()` somewhere, or unless it came from `stdin` I guess ;-)